# Doubly linked list of process control block in Operating Systems

Tags: operating-system, scheduling, doubly-linked-list, rtos

What is the reasoning behind maintaining doubly linked lists of PCB's(process control blocks) in an OS for scheduling. I have seen this mentioned multiple times for Real time operating systems.

I would ideally go for a circular singly linked list , so that you could do a round robin and reach back to 1st task after looking to all. You could also sort it by priority...

But, why a doubly linked list?

Comment: people voting to close the question, please comment on why :).

Comment: Umm.. because you can then easily and quickly move a TCB from one list to another?

Comment: @nikel I didnt vote to close, but probably because its a bit broad, and a bit opinion based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made the assumption that you would always want to start at the head, and work towards the end of the list. This may not be true. Say you are swapping one process out (eg it is pending on a sempahore). You already have the current process control block, so it makes sense to start using the information you have rather than iterate through the entire list.

Because the PCB has a reference to both the previous and the next, you can cut that node out of the running-list, and move to a pended-list, or from a pended-list back into a ready-to-run list etc, without having to iterate all the way through.

Comment: So, if we move a PCB out to another queue, we will have to link the PCB before it and after it. For that we could use a doubly linked list. Is that the idea you are trying to suggest?

Comment: Yes..... It doesnt require to be a doubly linked list, its just more efficient, assuming you already have the node you want to move.